# How can I make Telerik TabStrip tabs persist between page requests?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik

in Telerik ASP.NET MVC TabStrip, I want the page to remember which tab was selected last and persist the selection through multiple page requests. 
What I have is a partial view that shows in multiple pages and it contains the TabStrip. With SelectedIndex the set tab always get selected, which nullifies user's selection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I couldn't find any official way of doing this through the Telerik APIs, nor any useful advice on their forum, so I decided to go it my own way with the use of:

1. Html.Telerik().TabStrip().ClientEvents() both the OnSelect() and OnLoad()
2. [The cookie plugin for jQuery](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie)

Then I wired them up as below, in the partial view that contains the TabStrip.

```
.ClientEvents(events => events
.OnSelect(() =>
{ 
    %>
    function(e) {
        var item = $(e.item);
        $.cookie('selectedTabIndex', item.index(), { path: '/' });
    }
    <%
})
.OnLoad(() =>
{ 
    %>
    function(e) {
        var tabStrip = $("#TabStrip").data("tTabStrip");
        var index = $.cookie('selectedTabIndex');
        var domElement = $("li", tabStrip.element)[index];
        tabStrip.select(domElement);
    }
    <%
})
```

)

*Edit: I realised that my answer was little bit lacking in explanation so I've added:*

> In case it's not obvious, the OnSelect
>   is capturing the index of the selected
>   tab when it is selected and writing
>   that to a cookie called
>   selectedTabIndex. The path is being
>   set so it will cover our whole site,
>   but if you leave that out it will
>   create a new cookie for each different
>   path (which may be your desired
>   behaviour). Someone more familiar with
>   the jQuery cookie plugin please
>   correct me if I'm wrong there, I
>   haven't used it much.
>
> Then in the OnLoad it's doing the
>   opposite, basically. It finds the
>   tabStrip, gets the index from the
>   cookie, then gets the domElement of
>   the tab at the index from the cookie
>   and tells the tabStrip to select that
>   domElement.

This seems to work pretty well in Chrome and IE, but there may be some quirks in FFox 3.

I hope the Telerik team considers adding this to their API, as it strikes me as being a pretty useful feature to have baked-in. Apologies if it already is, but I couldn't find it in the docs.